# put list in textbox in c# windowsform

Tags: c#, list

So this is my code:

```
MySqlDataReader msdr = mysqlquery.Reader("SELECT * FROM amount WHERE id=@id", "@id", i);
List<decimal> decimallist = new List<decimal>();

while (msdr.Read())
{
   decimallist.Add(msdr.GetDecimal(1));
   TbAmount.Text = string.Join(" ", decimallist.ToString());
}
```

so TbAMount is suppossed to get 2 values, but it only gets one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you checked the count of decimallist in debugging mode? Also, you can move this piece of code outside the while loop `TbAmount.Text = string.Join(" ", decimallist.ToString());`

Comment: `where id=@id` condition means that you are going to obtain *at most one* record, not *two*

Comment: You should assign it after the loop, otherwise you overwrite it always. However, it should give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the string after the loop when the list is filled completely. However, that gives the same result as if you always overwrite it in the loop, so isn't the reason for this issue.

But you use `decimallist.ToString()` in `String.Join` which just returns the type name of the list. Since the string implements `IEnumerable<char>` it compiles but is certainly not what you want.

You should use:

```
while (msdr.Read())
{
   decimallist.Add(msdr.GetDecimal(1));
}

TbAmount.Text = string.Join(" ", decimallist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration replaces the value so move below line out of loop.

```
TbAmount.Text = string.Join(" ", decimallist);
```

Comment: `decimallist.ToString()` doesn't make sense ;-)

Comment: Corrected. Actually I just copied the line from the question itself. Thanks!